# Get Path of File found with os.walk

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.3

I am trying to expose the full path of a file found using os.walk. The walk function is working correctly and is exposing all the files I want however when I try to get the path it looks like it is exposing the path of the current working directory instead of where the file is located.

I tried to get the path by using os.path.join with the original folder name variable but these files are in subfolders

```
import arcpy, os, time, sys, shutil,codecs
import xml.dom.minidom as DOM
from os.path import basename
from arcpy import env

folderName = "F:\\MXDTest\\"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folderName):
    if 'CacheMaps' in dirs:
        dirs.remove('CacheMaps') #don't visit CacheMaps Directory
    for f in files:
        if os.path.splitext(f)[1]==('.mxd'):
            fName = os.path.join(folderName, f)
            print fName
```

This returns 
F:\MXDTest\BaseMapContent.mxd
F:\MXDTest\MunicipalBoundary.mxd

However I want it to return 
F:\MXDTest\General\BaseMapContent.mxd
F:\MXDTest\Boundary\MunicipalBoundary.mxd

I want to feed this string into arcpy.mapping.MapDocument()

Comment: this post answered my question! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730173/python-cant-get-full-path-name-of-file

Comment: As an aside, since 10.1 SP1 there has been an `arcpy.da.Walk` which is geodatabase aware.  I would now always use that in preference to `os.walk`.

Answer (score 1):

Switching `folderName` with `root` should solve the problem.

```
fName = os.path.join(root, f)
```